# something wrong with my asp button while adding it to a panel.. ASP & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a button and adding it to a panel

```
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.ID = "b_con";
        p.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        this.Controls.Add(p);
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Attributes.Add("value", "reply");
        b.Attributes.Add("id", Convert.ToInt32(r["Message_ID"]).ToString());
        b.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
        b.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);
        p.Controls.Add(b);
```

I got this error 
Control 'ctl01' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Panels are server controls. You don't need to add `runat="server"`. A Button has an `Id` and a `Text` property.

Comment: At what point do you add the panel to a page?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

The page you are adding it to needs to have this on it. And your panel must live within the form tags.

```
<body>
<form runat="server">

<!-- Panel must be added within here -->
<div id="messages_con">
    <asp:Panel id="b_con" runat="server" />
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

So the panel you add it to needs to be in your Html Code. You are adding a button to a panel that doesn't exist on the page. Instead, reference the panel in the Html (as seen above), like this:

```
Panel p = b_con;
//p.ID = "b_con";
//p.Attributes.Add("runat", "server"); -- Not necessary
this.Controls.Add(p);
Button b = new Button();
b.Attributes.Add("value", "reply");
b.Attributes.Add("id", Convert.ToInt32(r["Message_ID"]).ToString());
b.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
b.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);
p.Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm creating the whole thing in the behind code .. how can I make the runat server form  within the behind code?

Comment: Are you saying you don't have a Web page that you are putting this on?

Comment: I have a web page but all of its contents coming from the behind code, because the panels & the buttons are depending on database results. I can change the way that I'm using to do this, but I a newbie to ASP and obviously I don't know how .. :

Comment: What do you mean by ALL of its contents? You do have a <body> tag, yes?

Comment: I have a body tag .. and I have in it <div id="messages_con"></div> and I change the div contents from my behind code using InnerHtml

Comment: OK. I updated the answer with a solution that is tailored to your situation.

Comment: okay thanks for help :) but the problem is I was unable to generate this " <asp:Panel id="b_con" runat="server" /> " dynamically according to database results .. so I changed the way I did this

Comment: Good idea. There are always better ways when you are faced with adding/creating server-side controls dynamically from the code-behind files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Form.Controls.Add(p);

by using this we can add panel on form tag.